# continuity and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and {${x_n}$} is a sequence in $(a,b)$, then {$f$(${x_n}$)} has a convergent subsequence.

True or False? If true, prove. If false, give a counterexample.

I'm guessing it's true. Is it possible to show this by:
Let $T:= f([a,b])$. Then we show that every sequence in $T$ has a subsequence converging to some element in $T$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ is bounded ,and therefore $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a bounded sequence, hence there exists a convergent subsequence by Bolzano's lemma.

Comment: $f(x)$ is bounded because $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes, because $[a,b]$ is compact, and continuous function on compact set is bounded, and uniformly continuous as well.

Comment: The statement that continuous function on compact set is bounded is taken from the I.V.T?

Answer (score 1):

True. One approach is to use that $f([a,b])$ is compact (@OC just posted this answer). If a more "direct" approach is needed, then first pick a convergent subsequence of the $x_n$, say $x_{n_k}\to x$ then by continuity $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$.